# Label text not changed in code behind after I change it with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a label and change it's value with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("lb").InnerHTML = "10";
document.getElementById("lb").InnerText = "10";
```

In the page, the label value is changed but in code behind when i want use `lb. text` it shows the old value, not 10.

How can change the value with javascript (not JQuery)(not hidden field) and see the new value in the code behind?

Comment: Does the label have `runat="server"` set?

Comment: <asp:Label runat="server" Text="salam" ID="lb" ></asp:Label>

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1409047/43846) suggests using a hidden form field, which you can read in the code behind.

Comment: i know that but i want to use lable.

Answer (score 3):

aspnet label renders as span in to the client side:

I think that only controls that render as input and changed by javascript are updated on viewstate, so you can do this;

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="salam" ID="lb" ></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField id="hdlbl" runat="server" />

document.getElementById("lb").InnerHTML = "10"; // update client side
document.getElementById("hdlbl").value = "10";  // store value to code behind
```

C#

```
hdlbl.value ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't want use hiddenfield i want to find a way change lable not hidden field.

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine What you plan to do will be difficult if not impossible due to the way the aspnet works.
I had a similar problem and had to use a solution like this. Change control with js and keep tracking changes with a hidden field :(